# Installing linux on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux

I am currently having Windows 7 on my system. As I am planning to learn Linux thought of installing it.

But I don't want to have it as dual boot. Instead I want to use it when I am on windows 7 as a separate window. So, whenever I don't need Linux I should be able to uninstall it as any other program.

Is there a way? 
What are the tools I require?
Which Linux distribution will you suggest?

Comment: virtual machine?

Comment: Yes! Just like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a virtual machine. I recommend installing Oracle's [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). It is** free **and easy to use.

As for the distribution, I like Ubuntu as it is simple but not too simple to limit what you can do. From [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), you can download:

> Ubuntu 13.04 ("Raring Ringtail") / 13.10 ("Saucy Salamander") / 14.04 ("Trusty Tahr")  i386 |  AMD64
>
> Ubuntu 12.10 ("Quantal Quetzal")  i386 |  AMD64
>
> Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ("Precise Pangolin")  i386 |  AMD64
>
> Ubuntu 10.04 LTS ("Lucid Lynx")  i386 |  AMD64

Once installed, you can update to the latest version - when it is compatible. More info on that page

Answer (score 1):

VMware fusion is another powerful tool which you can use to install linux it gives better options and features then free applications but you have to pay for it.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily install `ubuntu` via `virtual box` Here i am giving a link below

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox

there is the detailed procedure for installing ubuntu via virtual box with each and every step (with images). Please visit it will fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

As the other guys said, what you need is exactly a tool hosting other OSs on the Windows simultaneously which for that there are very popular tools, VMware workstation and VirtualBox. Although VirtualBox is free but it doesn't show that it certainly is better than VMware. Anyway, there are many webpages comparing them with each other. As a suggestion, I recommend Vmware.
Ubuntu, Debian, Redhat are a number of most popular distros of Linux. In fact, choosing one distro among others depends on the where you work. 
Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) opertaing system. you will get installation instructions and other details from [virtualbox user manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html) . you will also get virtualbox images which can be easily deployed from [virtualbox.org](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) or [virtualboxes.org](http://virtualboxes.org/images/). For installation documents click [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/jny4e3xonyf/howto_create_a_virtualbox_vm.pdf).

Another solution is sites like [linuxzoo.net](http://linuxzoo.net/). Through this site you will be able to use a virtual machine and some study material also.

Answer (score 1):

There are many [Linux virtual appliances](https://solutionexchange.vmware.com/store/category_groups/virtual-appliances) ready to use, which you can run in the free [VMware Player](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0).

Alternatively, you can run Linux natively inside Windows using [andLinux](http://www.andlinux.org).